# Update matplotlib plot when new data are available

Tags: python, matplotlib, websocket

I've a python script that receives data from a websocket, and then they are elaborated. What I'd like to do is to create a plot with `matplotlib`, that shows two functions on the same subplot (I need to check their intersection).

I've seen in other posts [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/how-do-i-plot-in-real-time-in-a-while-loop-using-matplotlib) that I can use `FuncAnimation` or create a loop and put a sleep in it, but it's not what I need; since I receive data from a websocket I don't know when those data arrives, so I cannot use a loop. The only thing that I know about timing at the moment is that those data are slow, I can receive at most one new sample every minute, so there should be no need for searching another library like pyqt with greater real-time performance.

Those are some code snippet taken [around here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916824/matplotlib-updating-live-plot/69276235#69276235):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.ion()
import pandas as pd

n = 100
x = np.arange(n)
y = np.random.rand(n)
# I don't get the obsession with pandas...
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(time=x, value=y))

# initialise plot and line
line, = plt.plot(df['time'], df['value'])

# simulate line drawing
for ii in range(len(df)):
    line.set_data(df['time'][:ii], df['value'][:ii]) # couldn't be bothered to look up the proper way to index in pd
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.001)
```

```
import random 
from itertools import count
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

x_vals = []
y_vals = []

index = count()


def analyse(i):

    data = pd.read_csv(<your file which is updated or live data>)#u can use the pandas or any other data frame work
    x = data['index']
    y1 = data['readings']

    plt.cla()

    plt.plot(x, y1, label='Temperature') #in my case data is temperature
    
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.tight_layout()

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), analyse, interval=1000) #adjust intervals for call

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

As you can see they uses a loop or a timer. What I need instead is to update the plot when a new websocket message arrives, and it cannot be handled this way.

What should I do in order to update a plot when new data arrives?

Comment: Something like proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944621/dynamically-updating-plot-in-matplotlib?

Comment: When new data arrives, you just update the data of the lines of the plot with `set_data` .